# How to pass function result from parent component to child with C# Mud Blazor

Tags: c#, frontend, mudblazor

Parent component

```
<ChildComponent text="@parseString"/>

@code{
    public string parseString(string text)
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Child component

```
<MudText>@text</MudText>

@code{
    
[Parameter]
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

I just want to pass function results from parent to my child component but I am getting this exception

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: You need to pass an actual string as a parameter when you call `parseString` in your parent component (as the answer of Dimitris shows)

Comment: Or remove the parameter: `public string parseString() { return "Some text"; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ChildComponent text="@parseString("Hello world")" />

@code{
    public string parseString(string text)
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
<ChildComponent text="@parseString(Message)" />

@code{
    private string Message => "Hello world";

    public string parseString(string text)
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

[Online demo](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wOQmbYYfGMjRwxfL)

Comment: The exception is thrown by some other part of your code that you haven't shared. The solution above is working fine: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QOcGPuupchKLfXed